# Python script - launch nmap with parameters

Tags: python, nmap

The scripts launches the application nmap. Only it doesn't print out the var to the application nmap. It does however if I print them separately.

Looking for some suggestions, many thanks.

[Image script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyA6U.png) - [Image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Io8h.png)

**Script:**

```
import os
import subprocess

xIP=input("Please enter IP-address to use on NMAP port-scan: ")
xOP=input("Please apply options to add on port-scan: ")

print("Entered values: ", xIP + xOP)

command = "nmap print xIP xOP"
#os.system(command)
subprocess.Popen(command)

input("Press ENTER to exit application...")
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? As an aside, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Yes, I did any debugging, and I know it's the line - command = "nmap print xIP xOP". I did post the images to provide extra information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Split the program name and the arguments, the first item in the list it expects is the name of the program to run.

In your case, `subprocess.Popen(command.split(' '))` may suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
command = "nmap print xIP xOP"
```

This line is the issue. First, as [Uriya Harpeness mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64109246/1426065), [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) works best when the command is split into pieces in a collection like a list. Instead of using `str.split()` as they suggest, [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) is designed for this, as the example in the `Popen` docs shows.

However, the other issue you're having is that you've placed your variable names into a string literal, so they're just being treated as part of the string instead of being evaluated for their contents. To get the behavior you want, just reference the variables directly:

```
command = ["nmap", "print", xIP, xOP]
subprocess.Popen(command)
```